# How to estimate density in a "more general" parametric method? (in R?)

Tags: r, density-estimation, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

As far as I know, when estimating the density of a distribution based on a sample from that distribution, we can take two extreme approached for estimation. The first is to not assume (almost) anything on the distribution and use the ECDF (`ecdf`) or a kernel density estimation (`density` in R). The alternative is to assume a specific family (like normal, beta, gamma, etc.) and estimate the parameters (for example, with the `fitdistrplus` package in R).

What I would like is something that would be between these two options. For example, if I have 100 observations, I can "afford" more than just 2 degrees of freedom to estimate the distribution. But at the same time I want some general family of distributions (and not have everything locally estimated, as with kernel density estimation). For example, maybe to assume the data came from the [exponential family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family), with some subset of common functions for T(x), h(x), η(θ), and A(θ) (which would include the options for normal, gamma, etc.).

Comment: Take a "very general" family of distributions, like a many-parameter version of the exponential family, put "reasonable" priors on the parameters, then run this with your $n$ observations through MCMC to get a "posterior density"?

Comment: There are several options that you might perhaps see as "between" those.

One possibility -- you might consider mixture distributions. 

  Actually, both a KDE and an ECDF can be regarded as mixtures in their own right (i. a mixture density of the kernel and ii. a cdf of a mixture of Dirac delta functions, equivalently a mixture of Heaviside functions), but if you restrict the mixture components so they don't potentially grow with $n$ -- perhaps there's no more than a limited number of components drawn from only a few candidate distributions -- then it would be arguable a parametric family

Comment: Another possibility perhaps some form of log spline density estimate with a fixed number of knots placed at specified quantiles. Flexible enough to assume a wide variety of shapes without the number of parameters increasing as n increases.

Comment: Hi @Glen_b. Do you know of any code for log spline density estimation? I looked around and the implementation I found were not monotonic (causing the CDF to sometime decrease)

Comment: update: found the package "logspline". Any other recommendations?

Comment: HI @Tal ... was just going to suggest logspline on CRAN, but as you say you found it already; I've used it before to good effect (including in some answers on site here)